# Can't find all my starred mail

Tags: gmail

If I use the search keyword `is:starred` Gmail shows me only the recently starred emails not the ancient ones. Using the keyword `has:` (e.g.: `has:orange-star`) doesn't find them either.

How can I find all my old starred emails?

Comment: Do you get more than 1 page of results?

Comment: No, only 8 results, so far under the page limit

Comment: When I try I get starred results going back 10+ years, and they go on for multiple pages.